# How to focus Cocos2d CCButton in tvOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, tvos

I am porting an iPhone Cocos2d game into tvOS. I am not getting focus onto Cocos2d object like CCButton.
Can any one help to get it done?